# Docker Deployment of Griddb Encountering error

Tags: griddb

I have followed the [Documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/docker/#griddb-server-container) of Griddb to install Microservices based Deployment of Griddb.

First i have run this:

```
docker network create griddb-net
docker pull griddbnet/griddb
```

Then i have run the third command:

```
docker run --network griddb-net --name griddb-server -d -t griddbnet/griddb
```

but when i am trying to up the service using Docker Desktop it is showing:

```
2023-10-13 19:38:16 2023-10-13T14:38:16.254Z 1215ad27d89a 23 ERROR EVENT_ENGINE [130900:EE_TIME_DIFF_ERROR] (now=1697207896254, last=1697207896264, diff=-10)
2023-10-13 19:38:16 2023-10-13T14:38:16.254Z 1215ad27d89a 16 ERROR EVENT_ENGINE [130900:EE_TIME_DIFF_ERROR] (now=1697207896254, last=1697207896265, diff=-11)
2023-10-14 13:34:58 2023-10-13T14:38:46.094Z 1215ad27d89a 16 ERROR EVENT_ENGINE [130900:EE_TIME_DIFF_ERROR] (now=1697207926094, last=
```

Why is it showing this?
The Deployment is on my local machine and it is showing that Time Diff Error inside Docker Desktop Logs and failed to getting started.